# Code-First Entity Framework Custom Id Generated

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Is it possible to create generated Id with code-first EF, so basically I want to create Id string with custom format

here is my code, something like this.

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [DefaultValue("some script maybe")]
    public string IdCustomer 
    {  
        get
        {
          return value from attribute script DefaultValue
        } 
        private set {};
    }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression(@"(\()?(\+62|62|0)(\d{2,3})?\)?[ .-]?\d{2,4}[ .-]?\d{2,4}[ .-]?\d{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Phone number")]
    public string Custno { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Input is required.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; } 
}
```

is it possible doing something like that, or any other idea to solved that issue

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. What do you mean by *string with custom format*? Your `IdCustomer` property is `long`. Why can't you just create this string by yourself and assign to every new entity before saving to the database?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma ah I'm sorry, already edit that, so basically, I want to create ID like this for example C00001, C00002 ... C00010 , C0011 etc, with code-first, is it possible to create that in model? which means when I use `update-database` command in console package, will automatically generated and inserted in database

Comment: `update-database` refers to Database Migrations, is no way related to the model. If you want such a logic you either have to generate your Ids in C# and assign them manually *or* create some kind of trigger/computed column inside the database (e.g. SqlServer). So the short answer is: no, you can't.

Comment: Okey, so I have to create default format inside the sqlserver right? @FedericoDipuma